Sublime Text won't connect via SFTP, even though it works between same two machines via terminal
So for years I have had Sublime (ver. 3, licensed) SFTP into my server, MacOS to Ubuntu. I have touched nothing, other than regular Ubuntu updates on my server.
Suddenly trying to connect to the host gives me the error:

SFTP No route to host


From the same client machine I can still FTP into the server (both through an FTP app, and terminal)
Via Terminal I can also SSH into my client
Again, via Terminal, I can successfully sftp into my server.

The most I can tell from  auth.log is that I see when I SFTP in from a terminal on the client machine.  If I attempt to SFTP with an improper name and or password, I see all that as well.
But when I try to to SFTP in from Sublime, absolutely  nothing shows up in the logs.
Only my Sublime SFTP connection no longer works. So from the above, I'm guessing it's a Sublime issue?????
Can anyone point me in the right direction? Maybe tell me if there are other logs I can look at?
Thank you.
Just in case, here’s my config file for my SFTP connection, also unchanged for years.

"type": "sftp",
"sync_down_on_open": true, "sync_same_age": true,
"host": "192.168.1.151", "user": xxx, "password": xxx,
"remote_path": "/var/www/cgi-bin", "file_permissions": "755",
"dir_permissions": "755",
"connect_timeout": 30,


If I had to GUESS, I'd guess that your server's IP address has changed.  You probably use a host name in the other cases, but you hat an IP address here.

@TimRoberts My sftp server config file has the same IP address as I am using in Terminal.  As well, long ago, I gave my server a static IP to avoid such issues.

Is it possible Sublime changed the format of their configuration file?

@TimRoberts Since Sublime has been updated on my machine, not sure how that would affect me.

@TimRoberts Well, since I haven't done anything regarding updgrades to Sublime in a while: I would think it shouldn't be that.

Another test I did: FileZilla always connected via FTP (same two machines). It also connects to the server using SFTP.  So again, only seems to fail when Sublime is involved.

You've looked at both the Packages/SFTP and Packages/User config files to make sure there isn't a straggler?  https://codexns.io/products/sftp_for_sublime/settings

@TimRoberts Not sure what you mean by straggler.  Here is my entire config file:
{
"type": "sftp",
"sync_down_on_open": true,
"sync_same_age": true,

"host": "192.168.1.151",
"user": "xxx",
"password": "xxx",
//"port": "22",

"remote_path": "/var/www/cgi-bin",
"file_permissions": "755",
"dir_permissions": "755",

"connect_timeout": 30,

}

What I'm saying is that the Sublime SFTP extension looks in several places for its config file.  If it's getting another file before it sees yours, your settings might not be acknowledged.

@TimRoberts I only see one server file under ../Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SFTP and it's the one I created.  As a test I just made a new server, and left it as host "example." Using that to connect took a long time to fail, it was trying off of that file.  When I update the new file with my real IP and User info, it failed instantly.  So I don't think that's it.  However, it's hard to tell which files to look at.  So many options under user, default, SFTP, MySFTP, etc.  I believe I've opened them all.  If you know any particular file I should look for, am all ears.

@TimRoberts As well, going by the debug log, it looks like the correct info:
2024-12-27 12:52:43, SFTP: Starting connection
2024-12-27 12:52:43, SFTP Connection Args: ('/usr/bin/sftp', '-C', '-oPort=22', '-oConnectTimeout=30', '-oServerAliveCountMax=1', '-oServerAliveInterval=30', '-
oTCPKeepAlive=no', 'username@192.168.1.151')
2024-12-27 12:52:43, SFTP Read:
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.151 port 22: No route to host
